# Get the list (array sorted by last uploaded date) of files from http location using ruby

Tags: ruby

Need help with the following.

I have HTTP page that represents a remote folder with files inside:

```
https://example.com
|/share
|-/builds
|--file1.tar.gz
|--file2.tar.gz
|--file3.tar.gz
```

I was trying the following to get folder content but it returns nothing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
result = `curl -s https://example.com/share/builds --list-only | sed -n 's%.*href="\([^.]*\.tar\.gz\)".*%\n\1%; ta; b; :a; s%.*\n%%; p'`
puts result
```

Could you please let me know what is missed here and also would be great if you can provide some alternative way to get the file list.

Comment: Why you're using `curl` instead of build-in libraries like https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html or some gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract links from the index page HTML.

Try something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

index_html = open('https://example.com/share/builds').read
index_dom = Nokogiri::HTML.parse index_html
links = index_dom.css('a').each { |link|
  puts "#{link['href']} #{link.text}"
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me to show one more element.
my index page looks like the following(spacing are saved:
    <pre><a href="../"> ../</a>
        <a href = "file1.tar">file1.tar</a>   01-Sep-2017  12:00 1.0 KB
        <a href = "file1.tar">file1.tar</a>   01-Sep-2017  12:00 1.0 KB
    </pre>
......
How can I parse dat+time from here?

Comment: I can't right now, sorry. Why not start a new question and explain what you've tried so far?